# Scaling and moving an item at the same time

Tags: wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to create a storyboard that scales and moves an element to a specific position. The basic idea is there are a row of 6 small cards, clicking on one will zoom into a more detailed image, starting from the position and size of the small card and ending up with a large centered card.

The card doesn't end up in the X,Y position I specify, I believe because the scaletransform is also moving it. I saw that a matrixtransform may work, but couldn't get it to work, at least in WP8. Here is my original code, card is the small card for starting location, item is the large detailed card to be scaled and moved

```
    private void ZoomIn(UIElement item, UIElement card)
    {

        // setup
        var _Scale = new ScaleTransform
        {
            ScaleX = 1,
            ScaleY = 1,
            CenterX = item.RenderSize.Width / 2,
            CenterY = item.RenderSize.Height / 2,   
        };

        var transform = card.TransformToVisual(Application.Current.RootVisual as FrameworkElement);
        Point absolutePosition = transform.Transform(new Point(0, 0));

        var _Translate = new TranslateTransform();

        var _Group = new TransformGroup();
        _Group.Children.Add(_Scale);
        _Group.Children.Add(_Translate);
        item.RenderTransform = _Group;

        // animate
        var _Storyboard = new Storyboard { };

        // scale X
        var _ScaleAnimateX = new DoubleAnimation
        {
            To = 1.0,
            From=0.5,
            Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(.25)
        };
        _Storyboard.Children.Add(_ScaleAnimateX);
        Storyboard.SetTarget(_ScaleAnimateX, _Scale);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(_ScaleAnimateX,
            new PropertyPath(ScaleTransform.ScaleXProperty));

        // scale Y
        var _ScaleAnimateY = new DoubleAnimation
        {
            To = 1.0,
            From = 0.5,
            Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(.25)
        };
        _Storyboard.Children.Add(_ScaleAnimateY);
        Storyboard.SetTarget(_ScaleAnimateY, _Scale);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(_ScaleAnimateY,
            new PropertyPath(ScaleTransform.ScaleYProperty));


        // translate (location X)
        var _TranslateAnimateX = new DoubleAnimation
        {
            From = absolutePosition.X,
            To = 300,
            Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(.25)
        };
        _Storyboard.Children.Add(_TranslateAnimateX);
        Storyboard.SetTarget(_TranslateAnimateX, _Translate);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(_TranslateAnimateX,
            new PropertyPath(TranslateTransform.XProperty));

        // translate (location Y)
        var _TranslateAnimateY = new DoubleAnimation
        {
            From = absolutePosition.Y,
            To = 40,
            Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(.25)
        };

        _Storyboard.Begin();
    }
```

Comment: What is the container element all those cards? Can we get a screenshot? It is most likely that your existing layout conflicts with your transforms.

Comment: necessarily in c# or in .xaml will also do?

Comment: The main game board and cards are in a complex grid structure, but the large "zoomed" card  s in a large full-screen stack panel all on it's own so it can move anywhere, it just isn't ending up at the X,Y I specify

Comment: I would prefer C# but if there is a XAML solution I can convert to code that will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, the panel with the zoomed card didn't have a horizontal/vertical alignment, I set it to left/top, used CenterX/CenterY of 0, and movements are now pixel perfect